# Is there a way to AWS RDS postgres.log into CloudWatch?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to move the AWS RDS `postgres.log` files into AWS CloudWatch, but it seems there is no an easy way to do. Anybody have made this before?

Comment: you could log pg to syslog. there's a forwarding agent for cloudwatch for syslog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the out-of-the-box feature to publish your [RDS PostgreSQL logs to CloudWatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html#USER_LogAccess.PostgreSQL.PublishtoCloudWatchLogs).

**Note**: this feature is only supported for PostgreSQL versions 9.6.6 and above and 10.4 and above.